# Unable to extract all points when converting TIFF file to shapefile using gdal_polygonize.py

Tags: geotiff-tiff, raster-to-point, gdal-polygonize

**UPDATE**

I came to know that the [gdal_polygonize.py is not the right tool](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/431847/206013) for my purpose.

My aim is to convert the TIFF file to shapefile, so that I can get the elevation points. I already did the conversion using QGIS tool by running the *Raster pixels to points* algorithm. But I need an equivalent command line tool to use it for converting thousands of TIFF files.

*PREVIOUS WORK*

---

I am trying to extract elevation points from a TIFF file by converting it to shapefile using gdal_polygonize.py command on Linux

The conversion is successful, however the shapefile does not contain all the elevation points.

I am using the below command for conversion

```
gdal_polygonize.py NT60ne_DTM_2m.tif -f "ESRI Shapefile" NT60ne_DTM_2m.shp -fieldname elevation
```

Below are the screenshots of *NT60ne_DTM_2m.tif* and *NT60ne_DTM_2m.shp* which I have published on geoserver

**NT60ne_DTM_2m.tif**

[image]

**NT60ne_DTM_2m.shp**

[image]

I know the converted file is incomplete because I did the same operation in QGIS tool using *raster pixel to points* and below is its output

[image]
[image]

What am I missing here when using *gdal_polygonize.py* command for conversion. Why is it incomplete?

**UPDATE** : Add source file for other users to try [NT60ne_DTM_2m.tif](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wwOWnebYTnHz2zc_24j1ChWDZzDj9AYZ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Do I have to add additional arguments, so that it doesn't ignore those points while converting?

Comment: I suggest to edit your question and tell that already in the title or in the beginning of the main text.

Comment: @user30184, Alright I will add it to the content

Answer (score 0):

Gdal_polygonize is made for another purpose than "QGIS Raster pixels to points" tool. See https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_polygonize.html

> This utility creates vector polygons for all connected regions of
> pixels in the raster sharing a common pixel value. Each polygon is
> created with an attribute indicating the pixel value of that polygon.

The difference is the gdal_polygonize makes polygons, not points, and it is also merging the connected pixels with unique value into larger polygons.

The screenshot that you added is really weird. Compare it with my result. The polygons cover the whole area of the source DEM:

[image]

Could it be that you have published the polygon shapefile that gdal_polygonize creates with GeoServer by using a point symbolizer? Use polygon symbpolizer instead. And if your aim is to have one point for each pixel then gdal_polygonize it a wrong tool for you.

Comment: Ah I get it now. May I know which tool to use then to get one point for each pixel ?

Comment: What's wrong with the QGIS Raster pixels to points tool?

Comment: There are thousands of TIFF files which I want to convert. I am looking for command line tool to run it on my server, instead of using the QGIS Raster pixels to points GUI tool.

Comment: Have you tried to make a model with the QGIS graphical modeler?